How can I write an alias of an enum in TypeScript
I am refactoring a large codebase, which contained this definition:
export const enum Direction {
    NORTH,
    SOUTH,
}

and much code like this:
console.log(Direction.NORTH);

The new definition is this:
namespace abc {
    export const enum Direction {
        NORTH,
        SOUTH,
    }
}

With it, I can write this:
console.log(abc.Direction.NORTH);

Though, I don't want to change the code above to access the enum values.
I tried to write this:
namespace abc {
    export const enum Direction {
        NORTH,
        SOUTH,
    }
}

console.log(abc.Direction.NORTH);

export type Direction = abc.Direction;

console.log(Direction.NORTH);

Though, at the last line, I get the error:
'Direction' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.


const enums are pretty hard to deal with.

Export Direction as both a type and a value:
namespace abc {
    export const enum Direction {
        NORTH,
        SOUTH,
    }
}

export import Direction = abc.Direction;


You might want to link to the documentation for aliasing namespaces

Thank you. I didn't know I could write export import in the same statement. I couldn't find that in the documentation.
